# Java runtime.exec() error 2 but works in terminal

Tags: java, process, exec, runtime.exec

I am creating a command string by adding some strings together. If i debug my application and copy final string from variable it works perfectly in terminal. If try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd1);` where cmd1 is my string it doesn't work, i get error 2 (no such file or directory).
My code looks like this:

```
String cmd1 = sPath + " \"" + files[i].getPath() + "\" \"" 
+ files[i].getPath().replace(".wav", "_L.wav") + "\" remix 1";
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd1);
p1.waitFor();
```

The final cmd1 string is this:

```
 /Users/Me/Downloads/sox-14.4.1/sox "/Users/Me/Desktop/DB/A1199/Klu a1.wav"
 "/Users/Me/Desktop/DB/A1199/Klu a1_L.wav" remix 1
```

Any ideas why i get this error? I tried putting sox path into quotes but it doesn't help.

Ok, i tried this:

```
String[] cmd1 = new String[4];
cmd1[0] = soxPath;
cmd1[1] = "'" + files[i].getPath() + "'";
cmd1[2] = "'" + files[i].getPath().replace(".wav", "_L.wav") + "'";
cmd1[3] = "remix 1";

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd1);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
System.out.println(builder.command().toString());
final Process p1 = builder.start();
copy(p1.getInputStream(), System.out);
p1.waitFor();
```

But i still get same results... command works in terminal, but java app throws an error: `/Users/Me/NetBeansProjects/DataPrepare/sox/sox FAIL formats: can't open input file "/Users/Me/Desktop/DB/audio.wav"': No such file or directory`

Comment: Consider using a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). `Runtime.exec()` [doesn't work](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). At least you will be able to get what is printed on stderr.

Comment: I tried using `ProcessBuilder`, but i get the same problem.

Comment: Have you redirected stdout/stderr to a file? If yes, what does this file say?

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: @fge  I disagree with your implication that `exec` "doesn't work".  As we both should know from reading that article, it *does* work, but has many traps.  `ProcessBuilder` is better, but can also fail if those tips are ignored.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I compare using `Runtime.exec()` instead of a `ProcessBuilder` a little like using `system()` in C instead of `exec*()` -- although technically this isn't really true (`Runtime.exec()` doesn't fork a shell), I see no reason to use the unreliable way ;)

Comment: @fge  I agree with the basic thrust of what you are saying, but "doesn't work" is not the same as "unreliable" or sub-optimal.  I would only use the last term to describe `exec`.

Comment: @fge: `Runtime.exec()` and `ProcessBuilder` are entirely equivalent (look at your favorite JDKs implementation of `Runtime.exec()`, chances are it uses `ProcessBuilder` internally). It "only" differs in that `Runtime.exec()` is a more convuluted, harder-to-understand API. But the pitfalls are pretty much the same.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I don't really call "entirely equivalent" an API which allows me to alter the environment, std{in,out,err} etc and one which doesn't...